# Unable to send mail on AWS SES, email not verified

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I'm trying to send email on AWS SES.  I'm using Laravel to do that, using the built in `Mail` methods.

AWS is giving me the error:

```
Error executing "SendRawEmail" on "https://email.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://email.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com` resulted i ▶
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/">\n
  <Error>\n
    <Type>Sender</Type>\n
    <Code>MessageReje (truncated...)\n
 MessageRejected (client): Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region EU-WEST-1: example1@gmail.com - <ErrorResponse x ▶
  <Error>\n
    <Type>Sender</Type>\n
    <Code>MessageRejected</Code>\n
    <Message>Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region EU-WEST-1: mgriffiths@gmail.com</Message>\n
  </Error>\n
  <RequestId>645a3241-342f-11e8-8a1c-7ffffe0019e2</RequestId>\n
</ErrorResponse>\n
```

I understand the error.  I have not validated the example1@gmail.com address.  HOWEVER, that is the address I am *SENDING TO*.  The address I am *SENDING FROM* is noreply@mydomain.com, which *IS* validated in AWS SES console.

What am I doing wrong?

My code:

```
Mail::to('example1@gmail.com')->send(new TestMailable());
```

And:

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->view('emails.test_email')
        ->subject('Test Email '. time())
        ->from('noreply@mydomain.com');
}
```

To re-iterate, `noreply@mydomain.com` IS verified in AWS.

Comment: That documentation does not say I need to verify receivers.  If it did, it would render SES as a service pretty much useless, as I'd have to verify I own the email addresses of all of my users?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might be using the sandbox account. In which case even the receivers need to be validated.

In sandbox account following restriction apply

- You can only send mail to the Amazon SES mailbox simulator and to verified email addresses and domains only

You need production account to send to unverified receivers

See [Moving out of sandbox account](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html) for details about how to get the production account